# Google Analytics showing 0% bounce rate

Tags: google-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFUC.png)Google Analytics is showing me a bounce rate of 0% in Behavior> Events > Top Events but my overall bounce rate is 95%... what technical issue could be causing this?

Comment: Can you show me with a screenshot where you see the bounce rate 0% in Top Events?

Comment: i added the screenshot to the question since i dont know how to post a screenshot in the comments... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the screenshot in the question.